# Difference in datafile size on a same data?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb

I use MariaDB 10.1.16

I do very simple job this time.

**Select data from oracle** and Make **csv file**
Load that in MariaDB using **load infile data** command.
DB Engine is InnoDB.

Data row count is 6497641.
Both table is created same query.
PK is auto_increment and int type;

Row created by...

1. **TABLE1** - load infile data...
2. **TABLE2** - insert into TABLE2 select * from TABLE1...

size of tables is below.

1. **TABLE1** - 3.3GBytes
2. **TABLE2** - 1.9GBytes

Contents in mysql.innodb_table_stats is below.

1. **TABLE1**: n_rows(5438171) , clustered_index_size(196096), sum_of_other_index_sizes(12853)
2. **TABLE2**: n_rows(6407131) , clustered_index_size(106048), sum_of_other_index_sizes(12273)

---

I wanna know why the size of files is different.

thank you.

Comment: here is where you ask http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mysql ... In the meantime don't fixate on it and get to work ! :p

Comment: thank you @Drew . now searching answer of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the rows can make a big difference.  If the data is sorted by the `PRIMARY KEY` as it is inserted, the blocks will be packed nearly full.  If the rows are randomly sorted, the end result will be blocks that are about 69% full.  This is the nature of inserting into a BTree.

`n_rows` is just an approximation, hence the inconsistent count.  The other pair of values, I think, an exact number of 16KB blocks.

Since the PK is "clustered" with the data, the `clustered_index_size` is the size of the data, plus some overhead for the BTree on the PK.  Plus a lot of overhead and/or wasted space (as mentioned above).

Comment: I use `auto increment` `int type` PK. I expect that the order of data is not important and PK would automatically attached.

Comment: How did you dump the data?  Presumably, the _values_ of the PK are intact.  But the _order_ of the rows _in the dump_ is not necessarily PK-order.

Comment: Who make the csv file tell me that he didn't use sequential number. then I test new query based on your reply.
I make csv file having sequential PK column and test it. 
It's file size is smaller than before. I don't know that csv file don't have  sequential number. thank you. :)